# How can I separate nested list to two lists?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a data set with two dimensions as:

```
x,y={{{x11,y11}{x12,y12}{x13,y13}},{{x21,y21},{x22,y22},{x23,y23}},{{x31,y31},{x32,y32},{x33,y33}}}={{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 4}}, {{3, 6}, {4, 2}, {3, 7}}, {{2, 6}, {6, 
   2}, {7, 8}}}
```

How can I separate it to x and y as follows?

```
x = {{x11,x12,x13},{x21,x22,x23},{{x31,x32,x33}}={{1, 3, 5}, {3, 4, 3}, {2, 6, 7}}
y ={{y11,y12,y13},{y21,y22,y23},{{y31,y32,y33}}= {{2, 4, 4}, {6, 2, 7}, {6, 2, 8}}
```

Comment: See the [`Part` documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html). If `xy={{{x11,y11},{x12,y12},{x13,y13}},{{x21,y21},{x22,y22},{x23,y23}},{{x31,y31},{x32,y32},{x33,y33}}}` then 
`xy[[All,All,1]]` gives `{{x11,x12,x13},{x21,x22,x23},{x31,x32,x33}}` and `xy[[All,All,2]]` gives `{{y11,y12,y13},{y21,y22,y23},{y31,y32,y33}}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here we use two `Transpose`,but I think we can only use one `Flatten`.

```
list1 = {{{x11, y11}, {x12, y12}, {x13, y13}}, {{x21, y21}, {x22, 
     y22}, {x23, y23}}, {{x31, y31}, {x32, y32}, {x33, y33}}};
list2 = {{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 4}}, {{3, 6}, {4, 2}, {3, 7}}, {{2, 
     6}, {6, 2}, {7, 8}}};
Transpose[Transpose /@ list1]
Transpose[Transpose /@ list2]
```

[image]

Comment: good,how i separate it to two datasets, i think we can know the length and use iteration for sepating it

Comment: @Willymith  `Transpose[Transpose /@ list1]//First` and `Transpose[Transpose /@ list1]//Last`.

Comment: i want to make them as follow      x ={{1, 3, 5}, {3, 4, 3}, {2, 6, 7}}
y = {{2, 4, 4}, {6, 2, 7}, {6, 2, 8}}

Comment: @Willymith `{x, y} = Transpose[Transpose /@ list2]`.

Comment: thanks more from my heart

Comment: (+1) you could also use `Transpose[list1, {2, 3, 1}]` or `Flatten[list1, {{3}, {1}}]`

Comment: @kglr Wonderful! That is  I am looking for.

Answer (score 6):

```
Clear["Global`*"];
xylist = {{{x11, y11}, {x12, y12}, {x13, y13}}, {{x21, y21}, {x22, 
    y22}, {x23, y23}}, {{x31, y31}, {x32, y32}, {x33, y33}}}
numlist = {{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 4}}, {{3, 6}, {4, 2}, {3, 7}}, {{2, 
    6}, {6, 2}, {7, 8}}}

xy = {xylist, numlist}

MatrixForm@xy
```

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \text{x11} & \text{y11} \\
 \text{x12} & \text{y12} \\
 \text{x13} & \text{y13} \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \text{x21} & \text{y21} \\
 \text{x22} & \text{y22} \\
 \text{x23} & \text{y23} \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \text{x31} & \text{y31} \\
 \text{x32} & \text{y32} \\
 \text{x33} & \text{y33} \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 2 \\
 3 & 4 \\
 5 & 4 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 6 \\
 4 & 2 \\
 3 & 7 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 2 & 6 \\
 6 & 2 \\
 7 & 8 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

It is easier to visualize how to pair these columns up now.

```
x = Set @@ xy[[All, All, All, 1]]
y = Set @@ xy[[All, All, All, 2]]

{x, y}
```

> {{{1, 3, 5}, {3, 4, 3}, {2, 6, 7}}, {{2, 4, 4}, {6, 2, 7}, {6, 2, 8}}}

These values have also been assigned to the corresponding variables.